# Modx multiple contents with CKEditor

Tags: content-management-system, ckeditor, modx, modx-revolution

I am building a website with the Modx CMS.
Now i want to have multiple content area's on one page.

My solution: create an extra TV, set the TV with form customisation to the content, so the tv is under the content.

I created a template looking like this:

```
[[$top]]
<h1>[[*pagetitle]]</h1>
[[*content]]
[[!myCustomSnippet]]
[[*Other Content]]
[[$bottom]]
```

After creating the TV, i've set it's region to `modx-resource-content`.

---

The result:

[image: result]

As you can see, the text is messing with the CKEditor.

Somebody any ideas how to fix this?
(Using version `2.3.1-pl`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get TVs appear under the content textarea, it is better to use MODX system setting to that. Please goto Settings, and search for `tvs_below_content` and set it to `Yes`.

By doing this, the TVs will appear under the content textarea on single page instead of having their own separate tab.

Hopefully this helps.